# ios - xcode receiving Thread 1 EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I keep receiving the error "Thread 1 EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN, address=0xf286)"
my project is [in this zip](http://scramblr.us/Scrambler.zip)

**I have no idea what the error is, can someone please tell me?**

Comment: Usually means a bad pointer somewhere!  I suggest you single step through your code to find it.

Comment: The best thing to do is to run the Profiler.  Run "Profile" from the menu Product menu in XCode. Look for any and all errors regarding memory and fix them.  These errors can be a pain in the butt to track down and fix, but the profiler helps a lot.

Comment: @BrianV i ran the profiler and it gave me the "Uncategorized: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011):" how do i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:
    NSArray *masterWordList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"well", ...];
There are "floss" determined like a char* not NSString, so you forgot about "@", you should write @"floss".

And you better use some resource file to store a lot of strings constants...